# Multiple Xcode Versions W/ Xcode Server

Tags: ios, xcode, bots, osx-server, xcode-bots

Does anyone know of a way to use xcode server with multiple xcode versions? Especially since we currenlty have 3 versions of XCode right now?

Tried xcode-select via a script, but that did not switch the bot to use the selected version of Xcode as expected.

Also posted on the dev forums here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/262021

Comment: Why do you need multiple Xcode versions?

Comment: Because right now there are 3 versions of Xcode available to developers and the app behaves and builds differently on all of them.

Comment: Some of us are also building apps against the beta versions (for apple watch or new Swift 1.2) and want CI but also have production apps as well that require the current version.

Comment: Nada. We set up a VM in our office but is no where close to a good solution.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, since Xcode Server itself runs [from inside](http://honzadvorsky.com/blog/2015/5/4/under-the-hood-of-xcode-server) of Xcode.